# Why is LightGBM outputing this: Finished loading model, total used X iterations?

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I am new to the LightGBM model architecture.

> `Finished loading model, total used 15000 iterations`

It prints this message every time I train the model. It is being printed by this [line](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/dbc3d05c9c6f89d296a29b73a85a847c818892ad/python-package/lightgbm/basic.py#L2492) and I would like to understand why it is loading this model. What is the booster model? How is it trained? And why is it loading this model instead of training a new one?

Here's my code:

```py
lgbparams = {...}
lgbtrain = lgb.Dataset(data=self.train_x, label=self.train_y)

self.model = lgb.train(
  lgb_params, lgbtrain,
  evals_result=self.evals_result,
  valid_sets=lgbtrain,
  verbose_eval=False,
  callbacks=self.callbacks
)
```

---

**Found where this line is being printed**. Later on the code after training there is a line `copy.deepcopy(self.model)` and because of that somehow the LightGBM library prints the line in question.

Comment: The line you have linked to is only for when loading an existing model, and it is not supposed to be executed when training new models. Please post your training code, otherwise it's impossible for us to advise what may be going on.

Comment: @desertnaut edited the question to add code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also seen this print and it is during `deepcopy`. To reproduce it:

```
import copy
import numpy as np
import lightgbm as lgb

X = np.random.rand(100,3)
y = np.random.rand(100)
train = lgb.Dataset(X, y)
model = lgb.train({"verbose": -1}, train, num_boost_round=1)

# the printout is here:
model2 = copy.deepcopy(model)
```

The quick fix to switch off print during copy can be:

```
import os
import contextlib

with open(os.devnull, "w") as f, contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
    model2 = copy.deepcopy(model)
```

(I got this printout because I directly call `deepcopy` on lightgbm object.)